# Improper Integral of a periodic function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, improper-integrals, periodic-functions

I need to proof the following statement:

> let f(x) be a continuous periodic function that $0\leq\ f(x)$ and not
>   equal to zero. prove that 
>       $\int_1^\infty\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ diverge.

all I secceed so far is to prove that $\int_1^\infty\ f(x)dx$ diverges. any suggestion?

Comment: $$\int_1^\infty f\geq\sum_{n\geq1}\int_{nT}^{(n+1)T}f \geq \sum_{n\geq1}\int_{[na,nb]}\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T$ be a period of $f$ and $\int_1^{T+1} f = P$.  Then
\begin{align*}  \int_1^\infty \; \frac{f(x)}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x
   & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{kT+1}^{(k+1)T+1} \; \frac{f(x)}{x}  \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   & \geq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{kT+1}^{(k+1)T+1} \; \frac{f(x)}{\max ( [kT+1,(k+1)T+1] ) }  \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{kT+1}^{(k+1)T+1} \; \frac{f(x)}{(k+1)T+1}  \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{\int_{kT+1}^{(k+1)T+1} \; f(x)  \,\mathrm{d}x}{(k+1)T+1}  \\
   & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\int_{1}^{T+1} \; f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x}{(k+1)T+1}  \\
   & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{P}{(k+1)T+1}  \text{.}  \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T\geq 1$ (if $T<1$ start the sum at $N$ big enough to have $TN\geq 1$).
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathrm d x\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{kT}^{(k+1)T}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathrm d x\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha }{(k+1)T}=\infty $$
where $\alpha =\int_0^T f(x)\,\mathrm d x>0$. By the way, no need continuity as far as $f\in L^1(0,T)$.

Comment: The first inequality can be wrong if $\;T<1\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Indeed, thank you to point this fact. But it can be easely adaptable :-)

Comment: Yes, I know...just as the minimum of $\;f\;$ being zero or not. Little inaccuracies the OP can fix by himself, I hope.